# Jhipster 3.0.0 deploy to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jhipster

I'm trying do deploy a jhipster 3.0.0 project to aws, following the guide here: http://jhipster.github.io/aws/

The problem is that "yo jhipster:aws" command fails with the following error:

```
D:\Jenkins\workspace\CasualtyManager>yo jhipster:aws 
D:\Jenkins\workspace\CasualtyManager\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\aws\lib\s3.js:87
                httpOptions: {timeout: 600000}
                ^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Jenkins\workspace\CasualtyManager\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\aws\lib\aws.js:2:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. I resolved it by adding a `,` after `signatureVersion` and `httpOptions` in the s3.js file. It should look like this:

```
signatureVersion: 'v4',
httpOptions: {timeout: 600000},
```